# How can i align cell value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data table,

```
A     |B     |C     |D     |     E
abc|def|ghij|klmmm|ooo
lorem|ipsum|dol|amet|hel
```

But I want my result csv file looks like, when I use `pd.to_csv('sample.csv', sep='|')`

```
A     |B     |C     |D     |     E
abc   |def   |ghij  |klmmm |ooo
lorem |ipsum |dol   |amet  |hel
```

I am checking pandas document(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), but I don't see anything that I can align the cell space. Can I align the space for output csv file?

Thanks,

Comment: Why? A csv file is supposed to be machine readable, not look fancy. If you want it to look nice, load it with a program like Excel.

Comment: @timgeb Of course it is for machine. However, I am just curious if there is a way to do it.

Comment: So when you load your file, how are you going to know what whitespace was in the original values and what was added during the formatting?

Comment: @timgeb It is just casual curiosity that I was thinking if there is the way to make this way in Pandas. Didn't do any data cleaning or fomatting.

Comment: Alright, I don't think `pandas` has any builtin functionality for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your data are all strings you could do the following:

```
max_len = df.applymap(len).max().max() + 1
justify = lambda x: x.ljust(max_len)
df.applymap(justify).to_csv(sep='|', header=df.columns.map(justify), index=False)
```

Result:

```
A     |B     |C     |D     |E     
abc   |def   |ghij  |klmmm |ooo   
lorem |ipsum |dol   |amet  |hel
```

If you have string and non-string data may want to use `df.astype(str)` instead of `df`. For all floats dataframes you can use `float_format`.

Another (maybe even better) possibility is [to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html).